# Bilinear Interpolation on large arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, interpolation, sampling

I am using Java's `InterpolationBilinear` class to help me resample an array.  My current (and relatively small) test case is transforming a 10x10 array into a 20x20 array.  My issue is that the `interpolate(double[][], float x, float y)` method in this class is only resampling the upper-left corner of the 2D array I send it (0x0, 0x1, 1x0, 1x1).

Currently, it looks like I'll have to write some code to send the interpolate method a bunch of 2x2 arrays instead of the whole array.  There just seems to be a better way, any tips?

I am not interested in using 3rd party libraries, only standard Java and code I can write myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `InterpolationBilinear` class is supposed to do. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/InterpolationBilinear.html). The only thing it does is implement bilinear interpolation between four points arranged in a rectangle. The formula is [explained here](http://%5Bbilinear%20interpolation%5D%5B2%5D), and you can also implement it yourself pretty easily.

The question is: what are `float x` and `float y` in your example? For `InterpolationBilinear.interpolate` they're supposed to represent the fractional position between the four corners of the sample rectangle.

Or do you want `float x` and `float y` to represent element numbers in your array? e.g. (4.3,7.1) would mean interpolating between elements (4,7), (4,8), (5,7), and (5,8)? Then yes, you just have to plug those four values into `interpolate` (or your own implementation of that simple formula) along with the fractional positions 0.3 in x and 0.1 in y.

**EDIT** You have now clarified that `x` and `y` should represent the fractional position *in the array*, let's call it `raw[][]`, and assume it's 10 x 10 i.e. indices go from 0 to 9 in both dimensions.

To interpolate at `(x,y)` you just need to find what square `(x,y)` falls into, and interpolate between the four corners. In the x direction, the indices will be the integers immediately above and below `x*9`, i.e. `Math.floor(x*9)` and `Math.floor(x*9) + 1` -- same idea in y but with `y*9`. Now you have your four corners. Plug them into the formula. The fractional position will be something like `xfrac = x*9 - Math.floor(x*9)` and `yfrac = y*9 - Math.floor(y*9)`. Plug those in the formula as well.

This has to be repeated for each point in your target array. Note that the `x` in the paragraph above will be equal to `i/19` and the `y` equal to `j/19` where `i` and `j` are the indices of your target array.

Comment: I would like float x to be a place along the x-axis of my 2D array and the same for y on the y-axis.  So, if I have a 10x10 array, I want 0.5, 0.5 to interpolate at 5x5 in my array.

Comment: A 10x10 array will have elements 0 to 9 in both dimensions. So wouldn't a fractional position of (0.5,0.5) in the array represent (4.5,4.5) in terms of element number?

Comment: By the way, if you find an answer useful, then please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark to its left.

Comment: No, this method only looks at the upper-left 4 elements.  So (0.5, 0.5) would represent (0.5, 0.5).

Comment: Okay... is this what you want? I know that's what `InterpolationBilinear` will give you, but I thought you wanted something different. If you input (0.5,0.5), what do you want the output to be? i.e. what four array points should it interpolate between? Please clarify!

Comment: Ok, I'll be more detailed.  I'm starting with a 10x10 grid 0-9 on the x and 0-9 on the y.  I want to re-sample so my grid becomes a 20x20.  So, this means I need to sample at 400 different points in my grid.  Sampling at (0.0, 0.0) should look at (0, 0) in my grid and sampling at (1.0, 1.0) should look at (9, 9) in my grid.  The same is true for inbetween points.  (0.5, 0.5) should sample a new point in my grid, which would be at (4.5, 4.5).